# String to Array of string

Tags: ios, swift

I need to get array of string from a string e.g
from this string

```
"1. Grease cake pans with oil spray and preheat your oven to 350°F.2. Dissolve the coffee powder in the hot water.3. Combine the flour with cocoa powder, sugar, baking powder, baking soda, salt oil, buttermilk, eggs, in a large bowl."
```

to

```
["1. Grease cake pans with oil spray and preheat your oven to 350°F.",
 "2. Dissolve the coffee powder in the hot water."
 "3. Combine the flour with cocoa powder, sugar, baking powder, baking soda, salt oil, buttermilk, eggs, in a large bowl."]
```

on the bases of digits in the strings, in normal cases

```
String.components(separatedBy: <#T##CharacterSet#>)
```

works fine but in this case I can't figure
it out. thanks in advance

Comment: Whatever solution you use, make sure to think about ambiguous strings like: "1. Preheat oven to gas mark 2. (300ºF in the US.)2. Place item in oven from step 1.3. Mix other items." Working out the precise rules your string will follow (if there are any such rules), is an important part of making this robust. For example, does there have to be a period before the number? (But if so, think about changing the above string to "gas mark 0.5. (200º in the US).) Do you have any control over the input strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try matching any digit (1 or more) followed by a dot and a space. Then anything other than a period followed by a single period:

```
let string = "1. Grease cake pans with oil spray and preheat your oven to 350°F.2. Dissolve the coffee powder in the hot water.3. Combine the flour with cocoa powder, sugar, baking powder, baking soda, salt oil, buttermilk, eggs, in a large bowl."

let pattern = #"\d{1,}. {1}[^.]+.{1}"#

let sentences = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern)
    .matches(in: string, range: .init(string.startIndex..., in: string))
    .map {  string[Range($0.range, in: string)!] }

print(sentences)  // "["1. Grease cake pans with oil spray and preheat your oven to 350°F.", "2. Dissolve the coffee powder in the hot water.", "3. Combine the flour with cocoa powder, sugar, baking powder, baking soda, salt oil, buttermilk, eggs, in a large bowl."]\n"
```